# Im trying to run my calculator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, case

Im using swift code on Xcode 8. Can someone please help me out and figure out the error? It says the expression pattern of type 'string' cannot match values of type 'operation'. the error appeared at the switch operation and then the case that held × in it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

    @IBAction func Appenddigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func operate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        _ = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping{
            enter()
        }
        switch Operation() {
        case "×":
            if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * .operandStack.removeLast()
                enter()
            }
//            case "÷":
//            case "+":
//            case "−":
        default: 
            break
        }
    }

    var operandStack: Array<Double> = []
    @IBAction func enter() {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)
        print("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
    }
    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return NumberFormatter().number(from: display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3, `Operation` is the new name of the class `NSOperation`.

Your expression `Operation()` is creating an `Operation` object.

Whatever "Operation" is in your program, you need to rename it to something else. You should also explain what that code is supposed to be doing so we can help you fix it. The line

```
switch Operation()
```

Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`Operation()` is creating a new object of type `Operation` which cant be compared to `"x"`which is a string. What i think you want is to be calling a function called `operation` which would return a string.